# Insert specified text string X amount of times based on cell count and header value

Tags: excel, vba

UPDATED - Screenshots added / tables added

Newbie to VBA here, so apologies as I am sure this is a simple task but have researched and tested to no avail.

I am trying to re-format a standard report into a new file format for uploading. I am trying to insert a text value X amount of times based on a header value. Each column header differs (Dependent Care; Medical FSA; HSA), but must be spelled out as "Dependent Care FSA" or "Health Savings Plan" etc. and must run X amount of times down the same column (Column E) on a different sheet.

Here is a piece of the code I have written for this section so far, but can't seem to continuously find the last row of what was just inserted and continue to run down the column. The number of instances will vary week after week so want this to be dynamic. The column headers and values continue to go down from E1 to J1. The number of values are all the same, but those are what changes week after week. There may be 334 rows one week and 340 the next.

NumToRepeat = wksSource.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

```
    If wksSource.Range("E1").Value = "Pre_Tax_FSA_Dependent_care(DR1)" And wksSource.Range("F1").Value = "Pre_Tax_FSA_Medical(DR1)" Then
                   
        wksDest.Range("E2").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Dependent Care FSA"
        wksDest.Range("E2").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=wksDest.Range("E2:E" & NumToRepeat)

        wksDest.Range("E" & Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Medical FSA"
        wksDest.Range("E" & Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=wksDest.Range("E" & NumToRepeat + 1, "E" & NumToRepeat * 2 - 1)
                   
    End If
    
End With
```

I can get these two to stack up, but can't get others to stack thereafter. Whatever I write just copies over the second instance...

I just need HELP to continuously find the last row and pasting the text based on what is in the column headers. I apologize if this is all confusing (and elementary) but happy to clarify further and truly appreciate all the help in advance!!

[Source Data Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4wGS.png)

[End Result Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7X9V.png)

Here they are in table form:
Source Table Data Sample

| Paydate | EE_Code | SSN | EE Name | DepCareFSA | FSAMed | HSAemp | HSAer | Parking | Commuter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 05/14/2021 | ABCD | 123456789 | JOHN DOE | 208.33 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 05/14/2021 | EFGH | 111111111 | JANE DOE | 0 | 0 | 0 | 38.46 | 0 | 0 |
| 05/14/2021 | IJKL | 222222222 | JERRY DOE | 0 | 0 | 0 | 38.46 | 0 | 0 |
| 05/14/2021 | MNOP | 333333333 | JILL DOE | 115.38 | 0 | 190.38 | 86.54 | 0 | 0 |
| 05/14/2021 | QRST | 444444444 | JIM DOE | 0 | 0 | 190.38 | 86.54 | 0 | 0 |
| 05/14/2021 | UVWX | 555555555 | JEN DOE | 0 | 0 | 100 | 38.46 | 0 | 0 |

Trying to re-format to this... conditional based on what column the values are coming from to fill in column C and column E with column F being standard "Current" all the way down through all rows.

| EmployeeIdentifier | ContributionDate | ContributionDescription | ContributionAmount | PlanName | PriorTaxYear |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456789 | 05142021 | Payroll | 208.33 | Dependent Care FSA | Current |
| 111111111 | 05142021 | Payroll | 0 | Dependent Care FSA | Current |
| 222222222 | 05142021 | Payroll | 0 | Dependent Care FSA | Current |
| 333333333 | 05142021 | Payroll | 115.38 | Dependent Care FSA | Current |
| 444444444 | 05142021 | Payroll | 0 | Dependent Care FSA | Current |
| 555555555 | 05142021 | Payroll | 0 | Dependent Care FSA | Current |

This would continue on with values from column E, followed by column F stacked underneath, and so on and so forth with the corresponding contribution type listed based on which column it came from.

I am able to get everything setup (repeated SSN down the column, repeated dates... although in the incorrect format, corresponding values), but cannot figure out how to get the dependent names for column C and E to continuously find the last row, stack on top of each other while corresponding to the correct SSN and value... I haven't tried adding the column F where it says "current" all the way down but figure that's pretty easy?

Any and all help is truly appreciated. I am a proficient Excel user, but new to VBA and have been scouring to figure this all out. I am about 75% of the way there, but need help with these steps...

Thank you!

Comment: It's really confusing what you're trying to achieve. Could you post some examples of what you have and what you need (as screenshots)?

Comment: Hi Johny! I have added screenshots. The first image is the source data except pretend all of those "John Does" are different individuals (or employees in this case). The second screenshot is the end result I am trying to get to. I am able to get the SSN copied and pasted the correct amount of times, the date copy and pasted, the amounts from the source columns copy and pasted... but trying to now add a specific value added in column E based on which source column it is coming from and should be linked to each amount. I am also trying to do something similar for column C.

Comment: Adding sample data is a step in the right direction to improve this Q, but adding it only as an image is not helpful.   You're forcing anyone who tries to help you to retype your data, when you could include it as text.  Also, your explanation of that data belongs in the Q, not a comment

Comment: Ah - my apologies! I will adjust that this evening to include as text in the original post along with the details in the comment above. Thank you for the help!

Comment: What is X and how is it determined?

Comment: Could you contact me via Skype (search for: sekktor81)?

Comment: @norie X is determined by the number of employees in the source data. This can change from week to week... so may be 330 one week... and if we hire new employees - that would jump or vice versa if we terminate employees.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution for your case. Tune sheets' names to ones you need. The helper `SetTags` function merely selects appropriate names based on header's value. It uses `ByRef` in order to change these variables directly (and not use function which would return array). Before calling `SetTags` we need to clear these variables - this will give us a chance to catch an error if you misspell some text in `SetTags` (in this case there will be empty cells on the final worksheet). If we don't clear them and you have misspelled some text, you will get wrong text on the final worksheet. Also code uses two ranges - one with header (`rngTable`) and one without header (`rngData`). `rngData` lets us easily transfer data to final worksheet without any further calculations. Finally, since we know that the number of rows being copied is always the same, the next row (to insert to on the final worksheet) is calculated as current next row plus this number of rows.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Transfer()

    Dim wksSource As Worksheet, wksDest As Worksheet
    Dim rngTable As Range, rngData As Range
    Dim rowsCount&, nextRow&, col&
    Dim strContribDesc$, strPlanName$
    
    Set wksSource = Worksheets("SOURCE SAMPLE")
    Set wksDest = Worksheets("FINAL")
    Set rngTable = wksSource.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    With rngTable: Set rngData = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1): End With
    nextRow = 2: rowsCount = rngData.Rows.Count
    
    With wksDest
        .[A1].CurrentRegion.Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete '//Delete old data
        For col = 5 To 10
            strContribDesc = vbNullString: strPlanName = vbNullString
            Call SetTags(rngTable.Rows(1).Cells(col), strContribDesc, strPlanName)
            .Cells(nextRow, "A").Resize(rowsCount).Value = rngData.Columns(3).Value   '//EmployeeIdentifier
            .Cells(nextRow, "B").Resize(rowsCount).Value = rngData.Columns(1).Value   '//ContributionDate
            .Cells(nextRow, "C").Resize(rowsCount).Value = strContribDesc             '//ContributionDescription
            .Cells(nextRow, "D").Resize(rowsCount).Value = rngData.Columns(col).Value '//ContributionAmount
            .Cells(nextRow, "E").Resize(rowsCount).Value = strPlanName                '//PlanName
            .Cells(nextRow, "F").Resize(rowsCount).Value = "Current"                  '//PriorTaxYear
            nextRow = nextRow + rowsCount
        Next
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Well done!", vbInformation

End Sub

Private Sub SetTags(strHeader$, ByRef strContribDesc$, ByRef strPlanName$)
    Select Case strHeader
        Case "Pre_Tax_FSA_Dependent_care(DR1)"
            strContribDesc = "Payroll"
            strPlanName = "Dependent Care FSA"
        Case "Pre_Tax_FSA_Medical(DR1)"
            strContribDesc = "Payroll"
            strPlanName = "Medical FSA"
        Case "Pre_Tax_HSA_Employee(DR1)"
            strContribDesc = "Payroll"
            strPlanName = "Health Savings Plan"
        Case "Pre_Tax_HSA_Employer(DR1)"
            strContribDesc = "Employer"
            strPlanName = "Health Savings Plan"
        Case "Parking_Benefit(DR1)"
            strContribDesc = "Payroll"
            strPlanName = "Parking"
        Case "Commuter_Benefit(DR1)"
            strContribDesc = "Payroll"
            strPlanName = "Parking"
    End Select
End Sub
```